# New dataframe from old using groups of elements as headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I would like to transform a dataframe into one with equivalent information but slightly reorganized. As it stands I have a matrix, let's call it A which looks like this: A = [companies, day, close] with headers corresponding to the names in A (where the actual elements are names, dates and prices respectively). I would like a matrix B such that the indexes are dates, the columns are prices and each column corresponds to a company.

I've attempted groupby, pivot_table and perusing the old answers with questions similar to mine to no avail. To import the data I simply use

```
data = pd.read_excel('finbas.xlsx', index_col=1,
                     usecols = ["name", "day", "lastad"])
```

Which gives something like

```
day           name         price
1997-01-03    Acompany     97.5423
1997-01-04    Acompany     98.4234
.
.
2019-07-12   Acompany      104.2158
1997-01-03   Bcompany       21.4531
1997-01-04   Bcompany       22.2331
.
.
2019-07-12   Bcompany       24.9873
```

Now I would rather the headers be the company names (only once - i.e. Acompany is the header with each of its closing prices in the column below), dates being the index and prices being the elements, i.e.:

```
            Acompany    Bcompany...
1997-01-03: []          []
1997-01-04: []          []
.            
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it :

```
          day      name     price
0  1997-01-03  Acompany   97.5423
1  1997-01-04  Acompany   98.4234
2  2019-07-12  Acompany  104.2158
3  1997-01-03  Bcompany   21.4531
4  1997-01-03  Bcompany   22.4531
5  1997-01-04  Bcompany   22.2331
6  2019-07-12  Bcompany   24.9873

df = df.groupby(['day', 'name'])['price'].apply(list)
df = df.reset_index()
df.index = df.day
df.drop(columns=['day'], inplace = True)
df = df.pivot(columns='name')
```

---

Output :

```
                 price                    
name          Acompany            Bcompany
day                                       
1997-01-03   [97.5423]  [21.4531, 22.4531]
1997-01-04   [98.4234]           [22.2331]
2019-07-12  [104.2158]           [24.9873]
```

Comment: Hey vlemaistre! This didn't quite do the trick. I edited the example output I get from importing the data, please take a look if you have the time. What I would like to do is take the price for each day for each company and have a matrix where the rows are the dates and the column elements is the price for that company on that day (just like your end result). I think the main problem is grouping the companies and making them into headers.

Comment: Actually, I also get "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'day'" when attempting df.index = df.day, any suggestions? That might be the issue

Comment: Doesn't my code give you my end result ? Is there any error raised when you execute the code ?

Comment: It did on a rudimentary test dataframe I made in a separate file yet when attempting for the one imported I get: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'day'"

Comment: What is the name of your column containing the day information ? If you type `df.day`, do you get an error ?

Comment: It is called day, I get the above error before your comment

Comment: After some tinkering I no longer get that error, however I now get: ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape - exactly the problem, I need the duplicate companies grouped

Comment: Ah ok ! I didn't include the possibility for duplicates in date/company. I edited my answer to include them now. Tell me if it works :)

Comment: Hey vlemaistre! That seemed to work! However there are no duplicate days for one company, it's just that each row contains [company, day, price] and there's no need for company to appear so many times. The problem now is each company has the same time span (1997-2019) despite some companies only having data for shorter time spans (such as 1999-2017). This leaves these elements as NaN but I'm sure there's a command to strip it from empty cells. Thanks!

Comment: Also - is it necessary that each price element is a list?

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196567/new-df-using-old-headers)